# GitLab in container

Tags: docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, gitlab, pipeline

Sorry as the title is vague. I have Jenkins and GitLab in two separate docker containers connected by docker network. I am planning to create a CICD pipeline for an application. Although the application's source code in in my GitLab as well as GitLab container, there are some log files and some extra files at many paths in the code. This application is not owned by me and was previously executed on a completely different server. My question is do I need to copy these extra files, log files to GitLab GUI, GitLab container and Jenkins container or I can just copy these to GitLab container. I want to know if my jenkins runs only with code from SCM or will it have access to containers?

Answer (score 0):

If those files are generated by the application, they should be re-generated when your GitLab-CI will checkout the application source code, build and execute it.

In that case, they will be in the GitLab-CI job workspace.
No need to copy them then.

Comment: No, those files are not generated by the application. My question is do I need to put all those files in the GitLab GUI or GitLab container?

Comment: @YashRao GitLab container, through a mounted volume (https://docs.docker.com/storage/#choose-the-right-type-of-mount) accessed, as in https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/blob/master/docs/configuration/advanced-configuration.md#user-content-the-runnersdocker-section.

Comment: @YashRao If that is not possible/practical, then yes, you would add those file in a dedicated repo that you could reference in your own repo through https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

Comment: makes sense, thanks. I want to create pipeline for python3 application using Jenkins. I am confused where python3 needs to be present? on which container?